# How to avoid re-creation of fragment A when i go from fragment A to B and then back from fragment B to A

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I want to avoid the re-creation of fragments when I back to fragment A from fragment B.

click flow: `A->B`

Back button: `B->A`

(in this case, fragment A is recreated how to save the state of fragment A.)

Comment: are you following any architecture component? or using fragment transaction

Comment: fragment transaction.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you need to *retain* an instance in memory of a Fragment that is no longer visible; presumably it's expensive to recreate it so you want to save it.

This is a code-smell in most cases (but because I don't know your reasons and haven't seen your code, I will give you the benefit of doubt) :)

Assuming you have a valid reason for this, Android offers Fragments a mechanism to be retained:

Directly from the Android's Fragment source:

```
/**
     * Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
     * re-creation (such as from a configuration change). If set, the fragment
     * lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated:
     * <ul>
     * <li> {@link #onDestroy()} will not be called (but {@link #onDetach()} still
     * will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).
     * <li> {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} will not be called since the fragment
     * is not being re-created.
     * <li> {@link #onAttach(Activity)} and {@link #onActivityCreated(Bundle)} <b>will</b>
     * still be called.
     * </ul>
     */
    public void setRetainInstance(boolean retain) {
```

Keep in mind the implications of doing so, for now your lifecycle is different and so are all the side-effects of expecting a normal lifecycle (and the memory impact of keeping a fragment around).

Alternatively, consider separating the Fragment's state from it into a ViewModel, Repository, or Beyond™, and let the fragment simply be told what its state it so it can be properly recreated in a "fast" and "efficient" manner. (I quote these because fast/efficient are in the eye of the beholder and because it's also still subject to Android rules...).

Now, I haven't also seen how you "navigate" and how you "go back", so you'll have to test this yourself. Ultimately, if the FragmentManager desires to destroy your Fragment, it's probably because it found no reason to keep it around (you could, keep a hard reference and deal with all that memory wasted... which is why I suggest you keep the "state" outside of the Fragment instead, because creating a fragment is not that expensive, if the fragment doesn't contain 2000 lines of code in onCreate...) :)

Comment: additionally, he can read this article - https://jacquesgiraudel.medium.com/problem-with-restoring-fragments-from-the-backstack-945dc3f7f5a5

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going from category fragment to sub-category fragment. You have to add the current fragment to the back-stack while the transaction happens like this -

```
val fragmentManager: FragmentManager? = fragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction? = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()

    val fragment = SubCategoryFragment()
    fragment.arguments = bundle
    fragmentTransaction?.replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction?.addToBackStack("category")
    fragmentTransaction?.commit()
```

Here the line  `fragmentTransaction?.addToBackStack("category")` adds current fragment to back stack.

And finally, you want to go back from sub-category to category fragment, do it like below,

```
 fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
```

it will recall the previous fragment.

This code is in kotlin, but I think you will understand the workaround.

Comment: But the fragment will still be destroyed in this case, won't it? All the backstack addition is saving the transaction so it can be done in reverse (e.g. when you hit back) but has nothing to do with retaining an instance of a fragment... am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, fragments will also be destroyed in this case.

Comment: yes, you are right, actually, it's not clear whats the questioner really wants. I have just given a generalized answer for the most common case. Let's see whats other says about it.